# how to send email based on user selected locale

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, localisation

Sending email based on **locale** that user selected.

[image]

```
$locale='en_US';
$emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
                                ->loadDefault('test_reminder_email');               
$emailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $iDefaultStoreId));
$emailTemplate->setSenderName(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name'));
$emailTemplate->setSenderEmail(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email')); 
$subject=$product->getName().$this->__(' test Ended');
$emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject($subject);  
$emailTemplateVariables = array();
$processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);
$emailTemplate->send($customer->getEmail(),$customer->getName(), $emailTemplateVariables,$storeId=null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$locale='en_US';
$emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
                 ->loadDefault('test_reminder_email', $locale);
```

will try loading the `en_US` email template.